# Can a GPLv3 project use BSDv3-licensed includes?

Tags: gpl-3, bsd

A company I work in has wrote an implementation of Reed-Solomon codes through [Intel ISA-L library](https://github.com/intel/isa-l/).

Now I'm trying to start a discussion about open-sourcing our code, and distributing as a dual-licensed project:

1. GPLv3 for everyone
2. A proprietary license for those who are willing to pay for it.

The nuisance here is that ISA-L header files are distributed under a BSDv3 license. Hence my question is: can we distribute our sources under a GPLv3 license, given they use the BSDv3 headers from the ISA-L?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by what the [FSF writes](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-compatibility.en.html) and as discussed in [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/304/can-i-take-bsd-licensed-code-and-distribute-it-under-gpl) and its accepted answer: yes.

Given those license versions: BSD is on all accounts at least as permissive as GPLv3. Thus GPLv3 puts more restrictions on code than BSD does, and BSD does not place restrictions where the GPL does not request at the same.