# Do significant changes to code allow a license change from 3-BSD to something else?

Tags: gpl, derivative-works, bsd, relicensing

Suppose person X writes some library foolib, licensing it under the 3-BSD license.

Person Y now takes the foolib sources and develops it further, making significant changes: More functionality, changes to existing API, partial rewrite of the internals etc.. But of course, it is still an evolved and changed foolib.

Can person Y release their modified library under another license? e.g. GPL or LGPL? If so, what is the threshold to the amount of change necessary so that the original 3-BSD license doesn't "stick" to it, and its legal use is restricted to the terms

Notes:

- Not a dupe of the Theseus paradox question, as that one doesn't address whether I can distribute a derivative work under a different license.
- Other related questions:

  - [Relicense BSD 2/3-clause code to GPL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/75436/63497)
  - [Can I take BSD licensed code and distribute it under GPL?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/304/can-i-take-bsd-licensed-code-and-distribute-it-under-gpl)
- If it matters whether the library is source-only or object+headers, please mention this. Also if other aspects of the programming language matter.

Comment: How about this?  [Can one take BSD licensed code and distribute it under GPL?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4149/can-one-take-bsd-licensed-code-and-distribute-it-under-gpl/4194#4194) (Note that this is not the same question you link to above.)

Comment: Thanks for nominating this for reopening.  The issue, to my mind, is that it's already completely answered within the three answers linked to, thogh I agree that none of them is a precise duplicate.  If you have any remaining question that's not addressed by those three, please edit this question to reflect it.